# Rails run sidekiq on a single worker with puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, puma

Hi I m new to Rails and was wondering how to configure Heroku in Rails 4 with Puma and sidekiq to run on a single dyno?

Currently my sidekiq jobs are queued but not executed..

Answer (score 0):

Each dyno is a separate process. So you can run only sidekiq or puma on one dyno.
If you want to use free plan, then it is not possible.

However, there was a workaround, when you can create another one app, and run sidekiq there. So your puma and sidekiq will share same redis db to syncronize.

Check this link:
https://coderwall.com/p/fprnhg/free-background-jobs-on-heroku

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is it adaptable from the Unicorn example given to Puma?

Comment: I don't have such information about puma. It is actually based on threads, so it doesn't spawn additional workers at all in basic setup.